# Codeigniter - selecting a database row based on one field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a codeigniter site and I have a database table of books - one record for each book with title, author, etc etc fields. I know how to get the db table contents and pass an object to the view and then do a foreach loop to get the values. I could print a table of all the data. However I then get a bit muddled. The page has areas for each book and the data for a book will be one row of the data array. So what I want to do is, if the author is 'this' value, find the correct row in which the author appears and then get the other fields. How can I do a foreach loop that finds the one row with the author's name?
I can't think how to do it -  I seem to go round and round in circles.
Help!

Edit: Code:

OK so here's the controller method:

```
public function index()
{
    $books = $this->Books_model->getbooks();
    $data = array(
    'body_id'=>'home',
    'main'=>'home_view',
    'books'=>$books
    );
    $this->load->view('templates/template_main_view', $data);
}
```

and here's the model method:

```
function getbooks(){
    $query = $this->db->get('books');
    return $query->result();
}
```

so I end up with the variable `$books` (which is of course an object, not an array) in the view and a `var_dump()` shows that it has all the data. So far so good. I can then use a foreach loop to get values.

Now I want to extract a single row/record conditional on the fact that it has a given value for 'author' and assign each field of that row to a variable that I can use them in the view. And then I want to repeat that for the other rows. I can't seem to work out how to do that.

Afternote:

I found a way of doing this but not sure if it's the best or neatest:

I do this:

```
if(isset($books)){
    foreach($books as $row){
        if($row->author == 'authorname'){
            $title = $row->title;   
         }
    }
}
```

it works but seems a bit clumsy/overkill??

Comment: Please show us you code that you have been working on where problem is.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a specific function for getting the book/s that matches the author name?

For example:

In your controller you can do something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['books'] = $this->Books_model->get_each_book();
    $data = array(
    'body_id'=>'home',
    'main'=>'home_view',
    'books'=>$books
    );
    $this->load->view('templates/template_main_view', $data);
}
```

The in your model, do something like this:

```
function get_each_book(){
    $this->db->where('author','authorname');
    $query = $this->db->get('books');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

This way, you are gonna filter the results in the model already.

Then in your view, access the variable 'books' through a foreach loop:

Example:

```
foreach($books as $row)
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that contribution which is really helpful. However, I have a number of book panels in the view (say 10) and I need a set of variables for each like $title, $author, $image, $description, $isbn. So I need to pass a variable with all that information and then break it down in the view, otherwise I would need to pass 10 variables to the view, wouldn't I?

Comment: Since the result returned by the query made in your model returns an array "return $query->result_array();" you can manipulate your data from there on. Just store each of them in those variables that you want